# docker is not able to pull yolo/orcadev

Tags: windows-10, docker-for-windows

In my windows 10 , I am trying to pull image using my docker from the docker hub using following command

```
docker pull yolo/orcadev
```

But I am getting following error.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.418]
```

(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
C:\Windows\system32>docker pull yolo/orcadev
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
C:\Windows\system32>docker pull yolo/orcadev
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:51301->[::1]:53: read: connection refused

C:\Windows\system32>docker pull yolo/orcadev
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/yolo/orcadev/manifests/latest: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

C:\Windows\system32>docker pull yolo/orcadev
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for yolo/orcadev:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

C:\Windows\system32>docker pull yolo/orcadev
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/yolo/orcadev/manifests/latest: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?account=khanzada1&scope=repository%3Ayolo%2Forcadev%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

Whats the issue here?